# Reading from a text file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that selects a artist and prints a word from their song (all artists and song lines are in a .txt and should be chosen at random).

I have gotten this so far:

```
def main():
    import time
    import os

    os.system('cls')
    print("███╗   ███╗██╗   ██╗███████╗██╗ ██████╗     ██████╗ ██╗   ██╗██╗███████╗")
    print("████╗ ████║██║   ██║██╔════╝██║██╔════╝    ██╔═══██╗██║   ██║██║╚══███╔╝")
    print("██╔████╔██║██║   ██║███████╗██║██║         ██║   ██║██║   ██║██║  ███╔╝") 
    print("██║╚██╔╝██║██║   ██║╚════██║██║██║         ██║▄▄ ██║██║   ██║██║ ███╔╝ ") 
    print("██║ ╚═╝ ██║╚██████╔╝███████║██║╚██████╗    ╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║███████╗")
    print("╚═╝     ╚═╝ ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝╚═╝ ╚═════╝     ╚══▀▀═╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝╚══════╝")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Made By *****")
    time.sleep(2)

content = []
with open('songs.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        content.append(line.strip('\n'))

    for i in content:
        if 'song 1' == i:
            print("")
        else:
            pass
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a random function.

At the top of the code:

`import random`

Then run:

`index = random.randint(0,len(content))`

to index it later just use:

`print(content[index])`

So:

```
import random
def main():
    import time
    import os

    os.system('cls')
    print("███╗   ███╗██╗   ██╗███████╗██╗ ██████╗     ██████╗ ██╗   ██╗██╗███████╗")
    print("████╗ ████║██║   ██║██╔════╝██║██╔════╝    ██╔═══██╗██║   ██║██║╚══███╔╝")
    print("██╔████╔██║██║   ██║███████╗██║██║         ██║   ██║██║   ██║██║  ███╔╝") 
    print("██║╚██╔╝██║██║   ██║╚════██║██║██║         ██║▄▄ ██║██║   ██║██║ ███╔╝ ") 
    print("██║ ╚═╝ ██║╚██████╔╝███████║██║╚██████╗    ╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║███████╗")
    print("╚═╝     ╚═╝ ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝╚═╝ ╚═════╝     ╚══▀▀═╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝╚══════╝")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Made By *****")
    time.sleep(2)

content = []
with open('songs.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        content.append(line.strip('\n'))
index = random.randint(0, len(content)-1)
print(content[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a songs.txt file and need to get it as a list seperated by lines then, save the result in another list. So, the way you would do that is:

```py
def main():
    import time
    import os

    os.system('cls')
    print("███╗   ███╗██╗   ██╗███████╗██╗ ██████╗     ██████╗ ██╗   ██╗██╗███████╗")
    print("████╗ ████║██║   ██║██╔════╝██║██╔════╝    ██╔═══██╗██║   ██║██║╚══███╔╝")
    print("██╔████╔██║██║   ██║███████╗██║██║         ██║   ██║██║   ██║██║  ███╔╝") 
    print("██║╚██╔╝██║██║   ██║╚════██║██║██║         ██║▄▄ ██║██║   ██║██║ ███╔╝ ") 
    print("██║ ╚═╝ ██║╚██████╔╝███████║██║╚██████╗    ╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║███████╗")
    print("╚═╝     ╚═╝ ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝╚═╝ ╚═════╝     ╚══▀▀═╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝╚══════╝")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Made By *****")
    time.sleep(2)

content = []
for line in open('songs.txt','r').readlines():
    content.append(line.strip('\n'))

for i in content:
    if 'song 1' == i:
        print("")
    else:
        pass
```